# Custom Unobtrusive Method - Only fire on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've hooked a function into the addMethod of Unobtrusive. That working fine...However, is there a way to stop it from being fired on blur()? Im only wanting it to fire on submit()?

Any ideas?

Here is a sample of the hook.

```
$.validator.addMethod("dataRelated", function (value, element) {

return value !== "Texas";

}, function (t, e) {
    return 'Witty Error Message!';
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to add some more information. Your provided code doesn't give any indication as to why it fires on `.blur()`. `Need more input`

Comment: It's been my understanding that All Validator methods do this. So I didnt feel the need to provided the implementation. I really just want to know how to override that behavior. I added an arbitrary implementation.

Comment: Need to mention that you're using jQuery Validation plugin. This is not obvious to all. I added the tag to your question.

Comment: You cannot disable `blur` validation (called `onfocusout`) for a single rule or method.  You can only disable it for the whole form or for a particular field.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. And thanks for the reference.

Comment: @philtune Thanks for your input. I will def keep that in mind next time.